# activating a sheet whose name is result of a variable

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub updateCells()
```

'iterate through sheets to update using the sheet names stored in a list in the current selection of several cells in a column

```
Set sheetList = Selection

For i = 1 To sheetList.Count
Workbooks("myfile.xlsm").Sheets(sheetlist(i)).Activate
'[perform some update operations]
Next i

End Sub
```

'this gives an error on the .activate line that has something to do with sheetlist(i) not being recognized beacause when I change sheetlist(i) to the actual name of a sheet "mysheet" then the code works.  What am I doing wrong?  Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: `i` represents a counter, as in 1-3 (sheets from left to right 1-3)

Try using `sheetlist(i).Name` in place of `sheetlist(i)`, assuming that you using "the actual name of a sheet 'mysheet,'" does actually work as expected as your say, and not being able to see the remainder of your code.

Comment: Does `Debug.Print TypeName(sheetList(i))` return `String`?

Comment: Try like this ~Sub Test()
For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
Debug.Print Sheets.Count
'[perform some update operations]
Next i

End Sub~

Answer (score 0):

Here, `sheetlist` being a range, `sheetlist(i)` will give a cell of that range. To get the value of cell you'll have to use either of the following:

- **.Text**
- **.Value**
- **.Value2**

So your code changes to:

```
Sub updateCells()
    'iterate through sheets to update using the sheet names stored in a list in the current selection of several cells in a column

    Set sheetlist = Selection

    For i = 1 To sheetlist.Count
        Workbooks("myfile.xlsm").Sheets(sheetlist(i).Value).Activate
        '[perform some update operations]
    Next i

End Sub
```

I am using `Value` property of the cell in the above code.

You can also write above Sub as:

```
Sub updateCells()
    Set sheetlist = Selection

    For Each cell In sheetlist
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(cell.Value).Activate
        '[perform some update operations]
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`Selection` returns a `Range` object.

The correct way to reference individual parts of it would be by using the [Range.Item](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841096.aspx) property, like so:

```
Workbooks("myfile.xlsm").Sheets(sheetlist.Item(i).Value).Activate
```

Comment: Thank you so very much to all who provided a suggestion.  I am grateful for the advice.  It turns out another solution is to modify my code just slightly to force the return of a string using cstr() as follows:  Workbooks("mybook.xlsm").Sheets(CStr(sheetList(i))).Activate.  As always, many ways to skin the cat in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so very much to all who provided a suggestion.  I am grateful for the advice.  It turns out another solution is to modify my code just slightly to force the return of a string using cstr() as follows:

```
Workbooks("mybook.xlsm").Sheets(CStr(sheetList(i))).Activate
```

As always, many ways to skin the cat in VBA.